# split an array into 2 equivalent arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array a[10][50] and I created an array b[10][35] that stores the elements of a but I don't know how to create the array c[10][15] where the elements of array c are the elements left over from "a", can you help me?

```
int main(){
//Variables iniciales
float min = -32.768;    //limite inferior
float max = 32.768;     //limite superior
const int dim = 10;     //dimension
const int N = 50;       //poblacion inicial
//inicializar A
float a[dim][N];
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        float aleatorio;
        aleatorio = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        a[i][j] = min + abs(max - min) * aleatorio;
        cout << i<<" - " << j << ":" << a[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
//Dividir A en presas y depredadores
float preys_rate[] = { 0.7,0.9 };
float aleatorio = (float)0 + rand() % 1 / (float)RAND_MAX;
float rate = preys_rate[0] + (preys_rate[1] - preys_rate[0]) * aleatorio;
float N_h = round(N * rate);    //Numero de presas
float N_p = N - N_h;            //Numero de depredadores

//Asignar los miembros de A a H
float H[dim][35] ;
float fitness_value_h[35];
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N_h; j++)
    {
        H[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
}


//Evaluar la funcion en el elemento N_h
for (int i = 0; i < N_h; i++)
{
    fitness_value_h[i] = funcion_obj(H,35, 10 ,dim);
}


//Asignar los miembros restantes de A a P
float P[dim][15];
//float fitness_value_p[15];
//Si pertenecen a H[J], se ignoran
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    for (int j = 35; j< N; j--)
    {
        if (H[i][j]=a[i][j])
        {

        }else{
        P[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, array a[10][50] has some random data, and array H[10][35] has the values of "a" and I need a third array (in this example, P) P[10][15] that has the other "a" elements

Comment: So you've created two arrays but don't know how to create a third? Perhaps the issue would be easier to understand if you put together a [mcve] of what you have so far and describe more of what you're having trouble with. You should also explain any weird restrictions you have, like if you are unable to use `std::vector` for whatever reason. You could also explain what "equivalent" means.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just added the code

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the new array and simply add the remaining elements at the end of whatever loop you're using? If you know exactly how long the arrays are supposed to be, you can do this very easily.

It would be much easier if you included code in your questions so that we could see where the issue is.

EDIT: You are doing the loop in a more complicated way than necessary. Never set the initial in in a for loop to be the number of repetitions and subtracting.

```
for (int j = 35; j < N; j--) //BAD

for (int j = 0; j <= 35; j++) //GOOD
```

To fix your issue, simply add a condition to your loop to do something past the 35th repitition.

```
//Asignar los miembros de A a H
float H[dim][35] ;
float fitness_value_h[35];

float K[dim][15] ;
float fitness_value_k[15];


for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N_h; j++)
    {
        if (j < 35) {
            H[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
        else {
            K[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just added the code

Comment: So you just me to only use one loop to add all the elements from a to H and P?
like
int dim=10;
int N=50;

for(int i=0;i<dim;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
              if(j<35){
                   H[i][j]=a[i][j];
                 }
               else{
                   P[i][j]=a[i][j];
               }
          }
}

Comment: @CristianRamos yes that's exactly what I am saying. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I got the following error:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF609792D35 in Console Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000CA8425F1C8.

Comment: @CristianRamos this error is telling you that you are calling the array at a location where the array is undefined, EG arr[51] for an array of length 50. Look through your code and find where you are making an out of bounds call.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j <= 35; j++) //GOOD` Not good if iterating an array of 35 elements. `j <= 35` will allow `j` to reach 35 and access index 35 which would be the non-existent element 36. In general a `<=` in the exit condition of a `for` loop iterating a container will probably be a mistake, so investigate it closely whenever you see one.

Comment: I found a solution in Mathlab:
 % 2.2. Assign N_h individuals from "A" as herd members and 
            H = A(1:N_h,:);                                                     % Define the first "N_h" members in "A" as herd members
            end                                                                 % END
        % 2.3. Assign N_p individuals from "A" as predators and 
            P = A(N_h+1:N,:);                                                   % Define the remaining "N_p" members in "A" as herd members
But I'm a bit confused with the syntax used in Mathlab
Hope you can helpme